# Font-family embedding with CSS

Tags: fonts, font-family

I'm currently trying to embed a TTF font into my page, and then obviously will provide a back up font. For some reason it doesn't seem to embed, i have used http://browsershots.org/ to view my page in a multitude of browsers and none seem to pick up the embedded font.

My font face CSS is:

```
@font-face 
{
font-family: 'Tw Cen MT';
src: url('tw.ttf') format('truetype');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

This is included in all my CSS documents, and an example of how i'm implementing the font is:

```
p.toptext
{
font-size:17px;
font-family:"Tw Cen MT";
font-weight:bold;
color:#d5d3d3;
letter-spacing:0.5ex;
}
```

Now, does the link require ('../tw.ttf') to be added (../) for it to locate the font?

And another question relating to this, can i put my back up font in the font-family code, or do i have to manually add it in every time i link the font-family to a paragraph and anchor?

Thanks in advance, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this all type font face...

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Tw Cen MT';
    src: url('tw.eot');
    src: url('tw.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('tw.woff') format('woff'),
         url('tw.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('tw.svg#helveticaregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

Comment: I added "font-family:"Tw Cen MT", "Helvetica";" to the majority of my font-family tags in my CSS and it seems to have done the job regarding a back up font, a long with your code, but i can't tell if the embedded font has worked  http://browsershots.org/  is pretty useless.

Comment: Nope, just downloaded firefox with a bunch of add-ons to view it in other browsers and it still won't embed, i'm SURE firefox atleast allowed embedded TTF files.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this css

```
@font-face {

font-family: 'fontscorecomttwcenmt';
src: local('fontscorecomttwcenmt'),url('./fontscorecomttwcenmt.woff') format('woff'), url('./fontscorecomttwcenmt.ttf') format('truetype');

}

/* use this class to attach this font to any element i.e. <p class="fontsforweb_fontid_13141">Text with this font applied</p> */

 .fontsforweb_fontid_13141
        {
        font-family: 'fontscorecomttwcenmt' !important;
        }

/* Font downloaded from FontsForWeb.com */
```

Comment: Changed my font-family code to the above, and then subsequently changed all my font-family CSS to "fontscorecomttwcenmt", didn't work and didn't load the font. I'd imagine it should work embedding a font from my OWN server rather than retrieving it from the server it was downloaded from. My site is: www.crookedcartoon.co.uk/print.html for the record.

Answer (score 0):

My path is trying to locate the Font within the CSS folder because the @font-face code is placed within my CSS, changing the path of the font adding '../' to the beginning fixes it.

FIXED:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Tw Cen MT';
       src: url('../tw.eot');
       src: url('../tw.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
            url('../tw.woff') format('woff'),
            url('../tw.ttf') format('truetype'),
            url('../tw.svg#helveticaregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```